# Application keeps crashing because of database

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Our application keeps on crashing once per day (at the start of the workday). Because of what it seems connection with database.

> [31merror[39m: [SSL-QTEH-TD] E01000-SYSTEM_ERROR: [IBM][CLI Driver]
>   SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication
>   protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used:
>   "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "000.00.00.00". 
>   Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific
>   error code(s): "104", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001

I'm unable to determine why this is happening.

Comment: Add details. What type of application, which runtime, which Db2 and which plan. How do establish a connection? Are connections opened and closed? Show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a communication related SQL Error at the start of each working day. This implies that the network connectivity between your application and the database server was broken overnight, most likely for a scheduled downtime.

This could have been one or more of your app, the server your app runs on, any proxy or firewall servers servers between your app and the database server, the database, the server the database runs on.

Most likely it will be the database, allowing it to run reorgs and make backups. Next likely is a firewall, shutting down to allow maintenance. In any case your app needs to be able to detect the disconnect and recover.